# Is a capture captured even if it isn't used?

Tags: c++11, lambda, destructor

I'm using an async function that takes an object reference `&foo` and a callback `cb` as arguments. I want to prevent destruction of `foo` until the callback is called.

```
void async_thing(Foo &foo, function<void()> cb) {
    // do something asynchronously with foo
}
```

Is it enough to simply capture it in the callback lambda? Or does it need to be actually *used* in the lambda?

```
auto foo = make_shared<Foo>();
async_thing(*foo, [foo]() {
    cout << "Callback ran" << endl;
});
```

Might a compiler optimise the capture out, and delete `foo` prematurely?

Comment: AFAIK only the capture-all `=` and `&` selectively captures only the symbols that are used inside the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

**n3690, section 5.1.2**

> **15.**
>   An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the
>   capture-default is = or if it is explicitly captured with a capture
>   that does not include an &. For each entity captured by copy, an
>   unnamed nonstatic data member is declared in the closure type.

Above which we have:

> **3.**
>   The type of the lambda-expression (which is also the type of the
>   closure object) is a unique, unnamed nonunion class type — called the
>   closure type.
>   […]
>   An implementation may define the closure type
>   differently from what is described below provided this does not alter
>   the observable behavior of the program other than by changing:
>
> - the size and/or alignment of the closure type,
> - whether the closure type is trivially copyable (Clause 9),
> - whether the closure type is a standard-layout class (Clause 9), or
> - whether the closure type is a POD class (Clause 9).

From this I would conclude that:

- The capture makes a shared_ptr member in the closure type.
- The compiler is not allowed to alter that observable behavior.
- So your pointer won't be deleted until the destructor of the closure is called.